# Автоматизация mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Доброго времени суток. Проблема следующая.
Есть таблица. С началом новой недели (учитывая конкретный часовой пояс из другой таблицы) нужно совершать определенные действия с данными таблицы.
Вопрос: каким образом это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: Можно использовать любой удобный планировщик задач. Внешний (cron) или встроенный в MySQL http://adw0rd.com/2009/06/12/mysql-event-sheduler/  А вообще необходимость в обслуживании таблицы по расписанию чаще всего возникает из за неправильно спроектированной структуры БД (кроме случаев обновления данных из внешних источников)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь решения зависит от ситуации:

- Если у Вас есть доступ к штатному планировщику на сервере (обычно это cron), можно написать скрипт, исполняющий необходимые действия и в планировщике задать его запуск с нужной периодичностью;
- Если у Вас web-сайт, можно имитировать работу планировщика, храня где-то отметку о времени последнего запуска и вызывая нужный кусок кода с сервисным скриптом через заданные промежутки времени. Такую отметку можно хранить либо как файл на сервере (дата его модификации), либо непосредственно в вашей базе данный (например, как WordPress, в специальной таблице опций).